# Zebra 105SL (Plus) 2-way communications

Tags: communication, zebra-printers

I have written a printing application that works well. I can write files, update settings and do most all functionality from one console. But one aspect of the program has eluded me for quite a while: the ability to read the Zebra register/configuration values.

It would be good to periodically be able to read the values on the Zebra and compare them to default known good standards and to be able to reset them if necessary.

Currently, in order to see these values, I need to either use the built-in web page (networked printers only), print a report, or scroll through the printer interface. What I really need to is a method to be able to read these registers values and create a known good setup file.

Has anyone been able to find any SDK or trick to read these values using .NET (C# or vb.Net)?

The application is a windows desktop utility used on my shop floor and I communicate with the printers using either LPT and ethernet interfaces (as applicable).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the [Zebra Link-OS SDK](http://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/pc_net/) which has a lot of functionality when it comes to what you can do with Zebra printers. Specifically they have a section titled "Getting all printer settings and their configuration". However the code example they provide will not work unless your printer is a Link-OS enabled printer. If that happens to be the case then great! If not you can use the SGD class within the Zebra.SDK.Printer namespace to use Set-Get-Do commands to retrieve and change information. More information on SGD can be found in this [ZPL manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) under the SGD Printer Commands section.